# Chronograf set Alert for Gmail

Tags: gmail, alert, influxdb, chronograf

I need to set up a Chronograf alert for Gmail, but I can't do it.

What I've done are the following steps:

- I created a new Alert rules
- In the Alert Handlers section I have imported "email" and insert the alert threshold value
- I went to edit configuration and set everything as shown in the picture:
  [configuration for gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Cnq.png)

But when I press the "send test alert" button, no email is sent to me.

I also wrote the body of the email in the "alert rules builder" section just in case. but nothing has changed.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using less secure apps. log into your gmail account, or https://myaccount.google.com/security

Scroll down to "less secure apps" and enable that. If i recall, gmail blocks apps it considers to be less secure. I had to set this a couple of years ago to use gmail to relay alerts.

Also, your port number is wrong it should be 465 (SSL) or 587 (TLS)
[gmail smtp configutation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)